# Checking for names in nested named list in R

Tags: r, nested-lists

I have a nested named list in R and given a name, I want to check whether that's present in the names of that nested list.

For level 1 depth, `given_name %in% names(list)` is working fine. But how to search for names at different levels.

For ex: 
list `(a:1, b:1, c:( c_a:2,c_b:3 ))`. How to check whether `c$c_a` is in the list.

Answer (score 2):

I. Creating Nested List

```
  Your_list <- list(a=list(x=c(4,5)),b=list(c=list(y=c(8,99)),d=c("a","b")))

  names(Your_list)
  # [1] "a" "b"

  names(.Internal(unlist(Your_list, TRUE, TRUE)))
  # [1] "a.x1"   "a.x2"   "b.c.y1" "b.c.y2" "b.d1"   "b.d2" 

  str(Your_list)
  # List of 2
  #  $ a:List of 1
  #   ..$ x: num [1:2] 4 5
  #  $ b:List of 2
  #   ..$ c:List of 1
  #   .. ..$ y: num [1:2] 8 99
  #   ..$ d: chr [1:2] "a" "b"
```

II. Removing Nesting from the list

```
  New_list <- unlist(Your_list)
  New_list
  #   a.x1   a.x2 b.c.y1 b.c.y2   b.d1   b.d2 
  #    "4"    "5"    "8"   "99"    "a"    "b" 

  class(New_list)
  # [1] "character"

  str(New_list)
  #  Named chr [1:6] "4" "5" "8" "99" "a" "b"
  #  - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:6] "a.x1" "a.x2" "b.c.y1" "b.c.y2" ...
```

III. Converting it to list without nesting

```
  New_list <- as.list(New_list)
  New_list
  # $a.x1
  # [1] "4"

  # $a.x2
  # [1] "5"

  # $b.c.y1
  # [1] "8"

  # $b.c.y2
  # [1] "99"

  # $b.d1
  # [1] "a"

  # $b.d2
  # [1] "b"

  class(New_list)
  # [1] "list"

  str(New_list)
  # List of 6
  #  $ a.x1  : chr "4"
  #  $ a.x2  : chr "5"
  #  $ b.c.y1: chr "8"
  #  $ b.c.y2: chr "99"
  #  $ b.d1  : chr "a"
  #  $ b.d2  : chr "b"
```

IV. Accessing elements from Flat list `New_list` by names

```
  New_list$a.x1
  # [1] "4"
  New_list$a.x2
  # [1] "5"
  New_list$b.d2
  # [1] "b"
  New_list$b.c.y2
  # [1] "99"
```

Note: Here, the class is not preserved for the elements of flatten list. You will need to preserve the class when unlisting the list.

As you see all of them are character at the end.

Comment: Yeah, that worked. Thanks
Can u xplain what .Internal is doing there ?
names(unlist(list, True, True)) does the same.

Comment: Why did u use .Internal ? Just `names(unlist(list, True, True)) ` also does the same.

Comment: I have just started doing all this it is really core. For the start  you can type `?.Internal`, besides this there are many other functions for R core developers

Comment: One more thing, Can I make a nested named list into a named list of just level 1 by keeping the names same ?

Comment: I didnt get that, by level1 you mean just the top levels of the list, then that would be `a` and `b` here.

Comment: So for the list I mentioned in my question, I want to convert it into : `(a:1, b:1 , c.c_a:2, c.c_b:3)` .  I basically want to remove nesting

Comment: Do `unlist(Your_list)`see if that's what you want

Comment: I did that, but I am not able to access elements by their names.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122728/discussion-between-sowmya-s-manian-and-adarsh-kumar).